# Will Expired Managed Package prevent the access to standard object?

Tags: administration, security, insufficient-privileges

I'm facing the issue that none of my Org users can't create account since last 15 days. I've checked all privileges everything is fine even though the system administrator can't create account record. My Question is will expired managed package control the access of standard object?

Comment: I suggest you create a sandbox and reproduce there, then uninstall the expired managed package and see if that fixes the problem. I'm not sure how cleanly the behaviour of an expired managed package is removed: did the managed package interact with Account?

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer is No. Expired managed package cannot control access of Standard object.

You need to verify user's profile to check if `Create` permission is selected for Account object.

Comment: Thanks Santanu! I’ve created account as a system administrator for that profile also it shows insufficient privileges

Comment: what is the user's license you are using?

Comment: I’m using saleforce license